# failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/local/bin/code’: File exists error while trying to setup VSCode

Tags: software-installation

I looked at the  [microsoft docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/setup) but i am not good enough on terminal.

It says run this command:

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/vscode/Code /usr/local/bin/code
```

I customized it like this. But i don't understand what should be the second file path. First one is path to app as i understand.

```
sudo ln -s /opt/visual-studio-code/Code /usr/local/bin/code
```

I get this **error** when i run it:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/local/bin/code’: File exists
```

Comment: If you ran the first commands (`sudo ln -s /path/to/vscode/Code /usr/local/bin/code`) first, then it wouldn't work. Try running `code` in Terminal and seeing what it brings up. If nothing happens, then run `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/code && sudo ln -s /opt/visual-studio-code/Code /usr/local/bin/code`. This should re-create the symbolic link and you should be able to launch Visual Studio Code just fine.

Comment: it says "not found" if i run code

Comment: other code parts i tried and it said:
[3733:0912/021859:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(173)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.

Comment: refer [here](http://linuxpitstop.com/install-visual-studio-code-on-ubuntu-linux/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

emrah "file exists" means the symbolic link had been created before by you provided you had double clicked on the code file found in the extracted vscode zip file. 
Use these steps(1):

- create a folder say in your documents folder
- open a terminal and navigate to that folder
- in your terminal run 'sudo code .' (**Note: without the quotes**)

if the folder opens in visual studio code then that link you created perhaps unknowingly is working so your good to go, but if the folder doesn't open then that link is badly created.
Use these steps to correct the issue:

- run this from your terminal sudo rm -R /usr/local/bin/code
- **then rerun** sudo ln -s /path/to/vscode/Code /usr/local/bin/code
- now navigate to the folder you created previously from a terminal and try and run this from that folder '**sudo code .**' (**Note: without the quotes**), it should launch vscode with that folder.

Please do and let me know if it helped.

Comment: I tried on mac. But did not work. I had this problem on ubuntu. But same on mac too.

Comment: I made it work on mac. will try on ubuntu when i get home.

Comment: Hi emrah if it worked for you could you mark it as the answer?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't solve with your answer. And it has to work on ubuntu. I will try.

Comment: Emrah, could you please try it on Ubuntu and let me know..

Comment: You don't run graphical applications with `sudo`. Otherwise you'll end up with root owned files

Comment: @Anwar, yes your right. @atilkan do `code .` instead.